# Thread-Safe Code with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I rarely touch threading with my code, but was facing significant pressure to reduce runtime and so have attempted to utilize the parallel.ForEach loop.

The code executes calculations on bids (Items). The items have been loaded into a `List<List<Item>>` (the outer List being items of all the same ID and the inner list being the various items). I've included the class Item at the end.

```
List<List<Item>> queryItemsByAcceptID = phyBidList.GroupBy(bids => bids.acceptID)
                        .Select(group => group.ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

All bids have a property (settlement period) that separates them by time e.g. period 1 = 00:00-00:30, period 2 = 00:30-01:00 and so on. 
A bid from period 2 doesn't need any information from a bid from period 1. 
Hence, I separated the bids into their settlement periods, to run the calculations within a parallel.ForEach.

```
List<Item> phyBidList = new List<Item>();
var queryMassBySetPeriod = phyBidList.GroupBy(x => x.settlementPeriod)
                                .Select(group => group.ToList())
                                .ToList();
```

However, when I run the code I get inconsistent results both with the 'unParallel code' and with previous outputs when run multiple times. This leads me to think my code isn't 'thread safe', as the 'unParallel code' is both correct and consistent (but just way too slow).

Is this thread safe? And what should I do to generate consistent results?

I'm wondering if I should be locking the daylight out of everything...

```
acceptIdItem.FPN.Add(fpn);
acceptIdItem.qAboPosArea.Add(tempQABOposArea);
acceptIdItem.qAboNegArea.Add(tempQABOnegArea);
```

However, I'm not sure if locking is appropriate because the threads aren't (or at least shouldn't be) accessing the same variables... both because information from other blocks isn't required and bids only go through calculation once.

P.S. I've included code below, I've tried to remove what I don't think is necessary to make it shorter and easier to read.

```
Parallel.ForEach(queryMassBySetPeriod, block =>
{

Console.WriteLine("GroupBy UnitID");    
var queryItemsByUnitID = block.GroupBy(bids => bids.unitID)
                        .Select(group => group.ToList())
                        .ToList();

Console.WriteLine("GroupBy AcceptID");
queryItemsByAcceptID = block.GroupBy(bids => bids.acceptID)
                        .Select(group => group.ToList())
                        .ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Beginning mass interpretation...");
foreach (var list in queryItemsByAcceptID)
{    
    int bY = 0;
    foreach (var acceptIdItem in list)
    { 
        DateTime fromTime = acceptIdItem.fromTime;
        DateTime toTime = acceptIdItem.toTime;

        TimeSpan duration = toTime - fromTime;

        for (int i = 0; i < (duration.Minutes); i++) //qTime fix (duration.Minutes + 1)
        {  
            var queryPNdata = (from item in PNList
                            where item.unitID == acceptIdItem.unitID && item.fromTime <= fromTime && item.toTime >= fromTime
                            select item).FirstOrDefault();

            int time = (acceptIdItem.qTimes[i] - acceptIdItem.fromTime).Minutes;
            float boa = MathHelper.calcBOA(acceptIdItem.fromLevel, acceptIdItem.toLevel, (duration).Minutes, time);    
            float fpn = MathHelper.calcFPN(queryPNdata.fromLevel, queryPNdata.toLevel, duration.Minutes, time);

            acceptIdItem.qTimes.Add(fromTime + i * ((toTime - fromTime) / duration.Minutes));
            acceptIdItem.boa.Add(boa);
            acceptIdItem.FPN.Add(fpn);

            string[] tempBOUR = new string[6]; string[] tempBOLR = new string[6];
            float[] tempQABOneg = new float[6]; float[] tempQABOpos = new float[6];
            for (int k = 1; k < 7; k++)
            {
                //calculate tempBOUR/ tempBOLR/ tempQABOpos/ tempQABOneg
            }

            acceptIdItem.BOUR.Add(tempBOUR);
            acceptIdItem.BOLR.Add(tempBOLR);    
            acceptIdItem.qAboPos.Add(tempQABOpos);
            acceptIdItem.qAboNeg.Add(tempQABOneg);
        }

        int aZ = 0; //declared outside the loop to access later
        for (aZ = 0; aZ < (acceptIdItem.qAboNeg.Count() - 1); aZ++)
        {
            float[] tempQABOnegArea = new float[6]; float[] tempQABOposArea = new float[6];
            for (int k = 1; k < 7; k++)
            {
                //calculate tempQABOnegArea/ tempQABOposArea
            }

            acceptIdItem.qAboPosArea.Add(tempQABOposArea);
            acceptIdItem.qAboNegArea.Add(tempQABOnegArea);
        } 
        bY++;
    }
}
});
```

At the beginning information is assigned and the class is added to a list (phyBidList). Here is the class...

```
class Item
{
    public String unitID, acceptID, prevAcceptID, type;
    public DateTime fromTime, toTime, acceptTime;
    public int settlementPeriod, duration;
    public List<DateTime> qTimes = new List<DateTime>();
    public List<string[]> BOLR = new List<string[]>();
    public List<string[]> BOUR = new List<string[]>();
    public List<float[]> qAboNeg = new List<float[]>();
    public List<float[]> qAboPos = new List<float[]>();
    public List<float> boa = new List<float>();
    public List<float> prevBOA = new List<float>();
    public List<float> FPN = new List<float>();
    public List<float[]> qAboNegArea = new List<float[]>();
    public List<float[]> qAboPosArea = new List<float[]>();
}
```

****Edit****

In response to @calum-mcveigh, I changed the lists to concurrentBags using the below snippet, and other relevant changes. However, it still produces inconsistent results. I've put the full code on here https://pastebin.com/EgnE2285

```
ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<Item>> queryMass = new ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<Item>>();
foreach (var items in queryMassBySetPeriod)
{
    ConcurrentBag<Item> item = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();
    foreach (var bid in items)
    {                    
        item.Add(bid);
    }
    queryMass.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: P.P.S if there are any glaring errors causing it to run slow that would be appreciated as well. Thanks

Comment: If `acceptIdItem` or `acceptIdItem.boa` is accessed from multiple threads then yes it won't be thread-safe - since `List<T>` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Ultimately you need to provide a [mcve] (i.e. provide some code that we can copy and paste into a console app and run it that shows the issue) - there are too many grey areas for us to give meaningful advice (other than 'don't do operations that aren't documented as thread-safe without a `lock`) otherwise.

Comment: I've tried my best to do so below. There's a lot of dependancies so I had to include a lot, but it is complete and verifiable. The relevant parts are in the runInterpret() function. Line 324 onwards is the Parallel.ForEach code. Thanks
[link]https://pastebin.com/0vjwQ5d3
The code outputs to C:\spidergram\stackData2.csv... The offervolume column is where you can see the differences when run with parallel and without.

Comment: P.S. the individual `acceptIDItem` is not accessed from multiple threads, as it is a single bid, but the overall list (`phyBidList`) which includes the `acceptIDItem` is accessed. I considered this but thought it wouldn't be a problem as the List is used by multiple threads, but the items are not e.g. multiple threads do not need `phyBidList[0]` and so on...
P.P.S the code will say "error could not find file".. I have removed the other files so it will run faster and this will not affect output.

Comment: A whole lot of code and it contains nothing that could be thread-unsdafe. So the actual problem is somewhere else.

Comment: "error could not find file" doe snot make any sense at all... I can see no I/O.

Comment: _`phyBidList` is accessed_ - how? read only or are there updates? How much parallelism is there _outside_  this `Parallel.ForEach()` ?

Comment: queryItemsByAcceptID  does not play any roll ?

Comment: The program is meant to run with 12 files. I made the pastebin version only download 6 because all 12 aren't needed and slow it down.
queryItemsByAcceptID doesnt play a role in the snippet no

Comment: `phyBidList` is not read-only it is accessed but I've since changed it to be a ConcurrentBag<Item> as suggested

Comment: There is no other parellelism outside of the `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: `However, when I run the code I get inconsistent results both with the 'unParallel code' and with previous outputs when run multiple times.` What kind of inconsistent results are you seeing?

Comment: The program outputs to a csv... If on Excel/ LibreOffice you can total up the offer column and see that the number of bids change as well as the total value.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure thread safety you could use a concurrent collection such as `ConcurrentBag<T>` rather than a `List<T>`

You can read more about threadsafe collections [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

Variable `queryItemsByAcceptID` is declared outside `Parallel.ForEach` but is set and used inside it. Is stopped looking there, but maybe there are other variables with the same problem.

Comment: That was only done for the purpose of putting the code in one file. Removing it does not do anything as the variable is overwritten in the `Parallel.ForEach` loop, as I have tried and is shown below.
https://pastebin.com/yLKFVvj4